# How can request parameterValues be retrieved by EL?

Tags: java, jsp, el

Is it possible to retrieve an array of request parameters with same key using EL (just like the returned list by request.getParameterValues() in a servlet)?

I tried to retrieve it using this way:

```
${param["key"]}
```

but it only returned first value. Does EL allow to retrieve all values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just use `${paramValues}` instead.

```
${paramValues.key}
```

#### See also:

- [Our EL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info)
- [Java EE 5 tutorial - Implicit objects in EL](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnahq.html#bnaij)

Comment: Thanks BalusC, you are helpful as always :)